# Terraform DataSource failing to resolve ID for endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-ddb.html i want to ensure all dynamodb access is through the gateway endpoint.

I want to use a datasource to filter down the gateway details

```
data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "dynamodb" {
  service = "dynamodb"
  filter {
    name   = "service-type"
    values = ["Gateway"]
  }
}


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "policy"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "dynamodb:GetItem",
      "dynamodb:PutItem",
      "dynamodb:Scan",
      "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:sourceVpce"

      values = [data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.dynamodb.id] 
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "db" {
  name   = "policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy.json
  path   = "/"
}
```

This though isnt working
The plan is showing 9 numbers rather than the Endpoint ID

```
 # aws_iam_policy.db will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_policy" "db" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "policy"
      + path      = "/"
      + policy    = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action    = [
                          + "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                          + "dynamodb:Scan",
                          + "dynamodb:PutItem",
                          + "dynamodb:GetItem",
                        ]
                      + Condition = {
                          + StringEquals = {
                              + aws:sourceVpce = "808703518"
                            }
                        }
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Resource  = "*"
                      + Sid       = "policy"
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + policy_id = (known after apply)
      + tags_all  = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Can anyone suggest where i have gone wrong?
Changing the attribute to "arn" from "id" correctly populates the arn.  I am just unable to return the correct dynamodb endpoint ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `service_id` property:

```
values = [data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.dynamodb.service_id]
```

---

`id` is a "special" attribute that is used by Terraform to uniquely identify the resource. Generally speaking, you never really want to use it.